# Linearisation using SOS2

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, linearization

I am trying to linearise the following expresssion.

$C(k) = B(k) e^{-d(k)}, B(k) \ge 0 , d(k) \ge 0 $

I am trying to do this by using SOS2 sets.

I set $X(k) = e^{-d(k)}$ and I get $C(k) = B(k) X(k)$

By setting

$
u_{1}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) + X(k)) \\
u_{2}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) - X(k))
$

I get

$C(k) = u_{1}(k)^2 - u_{2}(k)^2 \\ 
 u_{1}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) + X(k)) \\
 u_{2}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) - X(k)) \\
 X(k) = e^{-d(k)}
$

Setting $y_{1}(k) = u_{1}^2, y_{2}(k) = u_{2}^2, step = 0.1$ I can linearise for $N$ points  as follows:

$
y_{1}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N (step (i-1))^2 \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i) \\
u_{1}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N step (i-1) \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i) = 1.0 
$

$
y_{2}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N (step (i-1))^2 \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i)\\
u_{2}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N step (i-1) \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i) \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i) = 1.0 
$

$X(k) = e^{-d(k)}$ is linearised as follows:

$
X(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N e^{step (i-1)} \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) \\
d(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N step (i-1) \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) = 1.0 
$

So finally, the  model becomes linearised to:

$
C(k) = y_{1}(k) - y_{2}(k) \\ 
y_{1}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N (step (i-1))^2 \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i) \\
u_{1}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N step (i-1) \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{u1}(i)) = 1.0  \\ 
y_{2}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N (step (i-1))^2 \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i)\\
u_{2}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N step (i-1) \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i) \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{u2}(i)) = 1.0  \\ 
u_{1}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) + X(k)) \\
u_{2}(k) = 0.5 (B(k) - X(k)) \\ 
X(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N e^{step (i-1)} \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) \\
d(k) = \sum_{i=1}^N (step (i-1)) \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{k}^{d}(i) = 1.0 
$

My question is,

1) Is what I have done correct?

2) Do I have to distinguish between different lamdas or  do they have to be the same?  ($\lambda_{k}^{u2}(i)$ the same as $\lambda_{k}^{u1}(i)$ the same as $\lambda_{k}^{d}(i)$)